# javascript test if div has text in it

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
1. <div id="div_Msg"> Test the div </div>
2. <div id="div_Msg"> </div>
```

In  the first instance there is the text  in the div. In the second instance there is no text. Using javascript how can it be tested if a div has text in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, you can do it like this:

```
if($.trim($('#div_Msg').text()) != "") {
    // Code here
}
```

In just plain JavaScript, do this:

```
if(document.getElementById("div_Msg").innerHTML.replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "") != "") {
    // Code here
}
```

Both cases get the text and trim whitespace off the beginning and end of the string, then compare it to an empty string.

Comment: Is trim really necessary? This works for me: if($('#div_Msg').text()) {}

Comment: In the example, the div without text has a space in it.  The trim removes the space. If you are sure there wil be no whitespace, then you don't need the trim.

Answer (score 0):

If using jQuery, you can do:

```
$.trim($('#div_Msg').text());
```

*Note:* elements **cannot** have the same `id`

Comment: That doesn't work. There is a space in the div and therefore a nextnode. At least in some browsers.

Comment: As @Mark says, you would need to `$.trim()` that value before checking against an empty string: `if ($.trim($('#div_Msg').text()) != '') { ..`

Comment: if($('[id$=div_Msg]').text() == null)
  { alert("yes text is not there"); }